# Create new table and insert columns having column1=kermit(value) and status= completed(value)

Tags: mysql, sql

Create new table and insert columns having
 column1=kermit(value) and status=
completed(value)

Comment: There's that Google thing, it's a website that you can make searches like "how to create a mysql table" or "how to insert values to mysql table" and it might give you some answers

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding it correctly, you need table creation and insert statements. You can use below query as template:

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE1]
    (
        [column1] VARCHAR(50), 
        [status]  VARCHAR(50)
    )

    INSERT INTO [TABLE1]
    (
        [column1], 
        [status]
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
         'kermit', 
         'completed'
    )
```